# Is this possible to create new configuration file in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

My Joomla site is hacked and now i want to safe my configuration.php file. i have set permission as well but i need more secure. So is this possible to make a new configuration file and call from current configuration file by require_once or include method.

Comment: if you do that what kind of additional security offers a hacker can access configuration.php can also see your new config !  read this http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/175/how-to-secure-a-new-joomla-installation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these for securing your `configuration.php` :-

1. Keep your `configuration.php` file outside `public_html`
2. Try to `encrypt` the content stored inside it.

First way will keep your file away from direct access through `URL`. Second will make it harder for hacker to crack what is written inside it.